# DAX Formula to calculate a month back

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm  working on building a KPI dashboard in Power BI with six different metrics.

All but two of the metrics rely on YTD data. However, the last two metrics are lagging a month behind. Does anyone know of a formula that can read either based on a filter or the most recent date in the data and calculate a month back?

I've tried both the dateadd and parallelperiod formulas with little success. I'd need to look 1 month back from the most recent date we have in the dataset to the calculations for this metric.

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific in order for someone to help you.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of date functions.
To get the last date in the data I think there’s a function LASTDATE.
To move backwards and forewords by x number of days or months you can use DATEADD

But as Alex commented you’ll need to be a little more specific to get a more specific answer